# How can I prove the associative property of this set?

Tags: group-theory, associativity

Let $(G,+)$ be a group.

Let $a$ belong to $G$.

Let $C(a)=\{ g \in G \mid g+a=a+g\}$.

Does $C(a)$ satisfy the associative property?

**WARNING (1) :** It is not valid to prove that $C(a)$ is a subgroup. Only that property is required.

**WARNING(2) :** The operator $+$ is not the addition operator. It is an unknown operator.

I don't know how to prove the associative property because I don't know how to remove the parentheses so that I can operate freely.

For example:

Let $x,y,z$ be in $C(a)$, then $$(x+y)+z+a=(x+y)+a+z=x+y+a+z=x+a+(y+z) =a+x+(y+z).$$ Since $g+a=a+g$, the statement is proved.

However, I have removed the parentheses directly rather than by some kind of deduction. I think this cannot be done, right?

Comment: Warning: if $+$ is not the addition operator, you should use $x\circ y$ or $x\cdot y$, but certainly not $x+y$.

Comment: The operator is associative when applied to elements of G because G is a group. So it is certainly associative when applied to a subset of the group.

Comment: This is not clear at all.  Of course the group operation is associative, that's part of what makes it a group operation.

Comment: @DietrichBurde It's a bad habit of some texts in abstract algebra (usually older ones) where they "assume" that users are going to be swallow AbAlg easier if they have nice, familiar symbols for arbitrary operations. In particular, many of them use $+$ as the "general" operation for an Abelian group or commutative operation. I suspect that is what has happened here. In my experience this just adds a level of confusion to the topic.

Comment: I would like to know how to write special characters for operators. Could you tell me what are the commands that this forum offers for these characters?

I would also like to know if I can write more complex symbols like the integral symbol. Is there a manual? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $S$ be *any* nonempty subset of $G$. Use concatenation for $+$. For any $r,s,t\in S$, since $S\subseteq G$, we can view $r,s,t\in G$. But then

$$r(st)=(rs)t$$

because $G$ is a group.

Comment: I agree.

One observation I would like to note is that, although associativity holds, the result of (rs)t = r(st) could be outside of S because its operation has not been proved to be internal (it actually is, but suppose we do not know it).

Thus, the associativity seems to be bound to the operator, while the inner operation characteristic is bound to the subset. That is why we can guarantee associativity even if we do not know if the operation is internal, right? It is to make sure that my concepts are correct.